# Eggbeaters cleats mounting to 3-hole shoe

Tags: pedals-clipless

I have crank bros. Eggbeater 2 pedals. They came with two hole cleats.  I need three hole cleats in a triangle pattern to fit my bike shoes. Is there such a thing and where can I get them.

Comment: https://www.worldwidecyclery.com/products/xpedo-xpr-adapter-and-cleat-set-for-3-hole-mounting-to-2-hole-spd-style-cleats-shimano-compatible-silver?gclid=CjwKCAjwv6blBRBzEiwAihbM-YFf01hFSF2J5s3Z6D1AQAN1bdbaD5EvRgoRG2vW1BLxTwOqe61JYhoCCccQAvD_BwE

Comment: While it’s possible I really don’t see a reason why you’d want to do it. You’ll get the disadvantages of both worlds plus higher stack height and weight.

Comment: Is N+1 just for bikes?  Or is it time to buy a set of two-bolt shoes as well?   Allows more time for shoes to dry if you have more pairs.   Do we call this the "Imelda Marcos variation on N+1" ??

Comment: I know you're probably trying to avoid buying more shoes, but there are shoes that support both cleat types e.g Specialized makes a pair: https://www.specialized.com/ca/en/torch-1-0-road-shoes/p/155209

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK three hole Eggbeater cleats don't exist - but - there are adapters for road shoes. I used to use this setup.

[image]

You can see the cleat is bolted to an adapter plate from the back. The plate has the 3-bolt pattern

The U-shaped thing on the left presses on the studs on the adapter plate and protects the cleat. I took it off so you could see the bolt arrangement.

Update: now I think about it I think the metal cleat is a special one that works with the adapter plate, not a regular 2-hole cleat, so the whole thing is really a '3-hole cleat'.